# Check EditText content for specific strings

Tags: java, android, function

everybody,

i've been looking on the net for a long time, but i can't find a solution - so i ask the professionals directly, haha.
My problem is that I want to check an EditText for characters. I am programming a calculator and here it should not happen that several calculation operators are displayed in the EditText. I could certainly work around this differently, but is there a function that can check the EditText for strings?

Here the entire calculation is written into an EditText.

Thank you!

Comment: Please explain proper what you want to look in edittext.

Comment: check this https://www.androidauthority.com/build-a-calculator-app-721910/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this function .. put it in every listener of your operators

```
 private void checkOperators(){
```

```
    //change the id with the id of your EditText
    EditText myEditText = findViewById(R.id.idEditText);

    //Get the last char
    String lastChar = myEditText.getText().toString().substring(myEditText.length());

    if (lastChar.equals("+") || lastChar.equals("*") || lastChar.equals("-") || lastChar.equals("/")){

        //Delete the first operator if they exist
        myEditText.setText(myEditText.getText().toString().substring(0,myEditText.length()-1);
    }


    // replace "newOperator" with your operator
    myEditText.setText(myEditText.getText().append(newOperator);

}
```